# Why to obfuscate a JavaScript code is a bad style?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, minify, v8, spidermonkey

I know, that in the society of the web-developers to use a **minifying process** for their JavaScript code representing as a well stuff. But if you want to obfuscate a JavaScript code, such an action will be marked as a bad and silly stuff.

***So why is it bad?***

For example, the obfuscation process of the .NET applications is in the opposite side, because the obfuscating makes a .NET program difficult to disassemble.

So why is obfuscation bad for the JavaScript code?

Does it make the compile-time slow for the **V8** or **SpiderMonkey** engines in browsers or maybe something else?

Comment: I think the premise is wrong. _Minification_ isn't meant to be used for obfuscation but to save bytes on transfer.

Comment: @OctavianDamiean Where did you see that I've linked the obfuscation and minifying process? I read again and have no suggestion about what are you talking about, because I've talked about these two processes separately.

Comment: For me the first paragraph kinda reads like that.

Comment: @OctavianDamiean Paragraph or a title? It's a different stuff. Title begins with a `Why to obfuscate...`, paragraph does from `I know...`

Comment: Thanks, I know how to distinguish a paragraph and a title. The second sentence in the first paragraph.

Comment: @OctavianDamiean And what? Obfuscation is representing as something incorrect often, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on obfuscator you use, it can influence badly on javascript performance. Moreover, some antiviruses can block such code from execution if they "think" it might be dangerous.

Comment: Anti-viruses blocking JavaScript!?

Comment: As far as i remember, AVG can block obfuscated javascript.

Comment: @OctavianDamiean: It depends on how what was used to obfuscate it. Some 'packers' will trip some heuristic detection in anti-virus. It's happened with me when I used Kaspersky, but that was like 8yrs ago. I'm sure they are better at it now.